# show customize 503 message when app pool is stopped

Tags: iis, 503-error

I have read a lot about it even here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2271887/custom-error-page-for-http-error-503

Nothing worked for me.

When the application pool is stopped, it will always show the Service unavailable message from the IIS

The page I have is 503.html

what can be done to make it work?

Comment: You should check why the application pool is being stopped and rectify the error. As an alternate way, you can set a recycle for the application pool.

Comment: I know that, what about my question though?

Comment: The 503 comes from HTTP.sys, not IIS. Haven't seen a way around this, but no IIS setting will have an effect on these 503s.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/error

The following HTTP errors can't be customized: 400, 403.9, 411, 414, 500, 500.11, 500.14, 500.15, 501, 503, and 505.